# How to embed Kivy or Kivymd GUI into PyQt5 App

Tags: qt, pyqt5, kivy, kivymd, qgridlayout

I have 2 basic apps (kivy & pyqt5) merged and separately they work just fine.
I am trying to embed KIVY or KIVYmD GUI into a running PyQt5 App.

### Full Code

```py
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQuick, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
##from kivy.core.window import Window
##Window.size = (280, 500)

Kivy_Style = '''
FloatLayout:
    MDLabel:
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.9,'center_y':.85}
        text:'LOGIN'
        font_size:80
    MDTextField:
        id:user
        hint_text:'Username'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.75}
        size_hint:.5,.1
    MDTextField:
        id:passw
        hint_text:'Password'
        password:True
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.65}
        size_hint:.5,.1
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text:'Login'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.55}
        size_hint:.2,.1
    
'''

class KivyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Kivy_Style)            
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     KivyApp().run()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 embed Kivy"); self.resize(300, 200)

        centralwgt  = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwgt)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwgt)
        # CntKV_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(centralwgt)
        try:
            lay.addWidget(KivyApp)   # error
        except Exception as _1srt_bug:
            print("_1srt_bug:", _1srt_bug)
            ## if you uncomment these 2lines below & comment the third, kivyapp run normal and when close we still sow 2separate GUI
            # kvGui = KivyApp
            # kvGui().run()
            # lay.addWidget(self, KivyApp().run) 
        else:
            CntKV_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(KivyApp)
            lay.addWidget(CntKV_widget)
            # pass
        finally:
            pass

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

### After many attempts:

I noticed, Kivy always run the Main windows even if i simply just import kivy modules modules; and when I add PyQt5 app and remove `KivyApp().run()`, 2 different/separate windows are running. At this point now i try to attach Kivy GUI into PyQt5 using `QGridLay().addWidget()` and  `QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer()`.

### when i try to embed the kivy `MDApp class` i get the error below

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
   addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'type'
   addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'type'
   addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'type'
```

[image]

Comment: As most UI toolkits, both Qt and Kivy use an *event loop* which must be run in the main thread, and there cannot be two simultaneous event loops, meaning that you cannot use them together: you use either Qt **or** Kivy. Also note that embedding foreign windows is notoriously problematic (mostly due to focus issues, but not only) and in many cases it just doesn't work.

Comment: @musicamante i am keep trying to figure out: Since Kivy uses OpenGL and therefore requires a backend that provides it, Please Can we do something by passing through  `from PyQt5.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget` ?

Comment: Sorry but I believe you're not understanding the problem. Importing modules doesn't make any difference on those toolkits: even ignoring the fact that QGLWidget [is obsolete since Qt 5.4](//www.qt.io/blog/2014/12/10/qt-5-4-released) (13 years ago!), the point is still that both Qt and Kivy are UI toolkits that have an event loop that must exist in their main thread. OpenGL is a *lower level* API that is used by a higher level programming interface (that usually interacts with the system) in order to show contents to the user. There's no "passing through", especially by just importing a module.

Comment: If you don't understand the above concepts, then I strongly advise you to take your time and do some further research on those topics. Programming is based on layers of concepts (and OOP adds even further layers to it), and it's important to understand the relations between those layers. Event driven toolkits cannot just work together as long as they live in the same thread (which is a limit and, coincidentally, somehow a benefit of Python). The fact that you want to use two toolkits that "can" use OpenGL is completely irrelevant: the hierarchy of the above "layers" just tells that you can't.